# Fade in/out CButton (set transparency)

Tags: winapi, mfc

In a dialog I have an options button. But I don't want it to be visible all the time, only when the cursor is over the dialog, and have a nice fade in/out.

I've tried several things to make the `CButton` transparent to it fade in/out, but not successful.

For example, I have tried `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and `UpdateLayeredWindow` but I can't get them to work, probably since the `CButton` is a child.

Any tips how to set the transparency of a `CButton`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have tried SetLayeredWindowAttributes and UpdateLayeredWindow but I
>   can't get them to work, probably since the CButton is a child.

[Layered child windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598(v=vs.85).aspx#layered_win) are supported since Windows 8:

> In order to use layered child windows, the application has to declare
>   itself Windows 8-aware in the manifest.

To do this, add a manifest section like this to your application through project properties > Manifest Tool > Input and output > Additional manifest files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

You propably want to declare support for [other Windows versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) too.

With the manifest in place, we can now turn a button into a layered window and set the desired transparency (alpha) level:

```
if( CWnd* pButton = GetDlgItem( IDC_OPTIONS ) )
{
    pButton->ModifyStyleEx( 0, WS_EX_LAYERED );
    pButton->SetLayeredWindowAttributes( 0, 96, LWA_ALPHA );
}
```

Adding this code in my overridden `CDialog::OnInitDialog()`, I got the following result under Win 10:

[image: Layered Child Window]

Note that the button looks like disabled, but this is just coincidence.

To make the button completely opaque again, remove the `WS_EX_LAYERED` bit:

```
pButton->ModifyStyleEx( WS_EX_LAYERED, 0 );
```

If you need to support **older OS than Windows 8**, you would have to use more involved techniques to achieve the same effect. Just some ideas that come to mind:

- Create an owner-drawn or custom-drawn button to have complete control over the appearance of the button, with the ability to fake transparency.
- Create an initially hidden button. Create a snapshot of the button as it would look like when visible by sending it a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message. Draw the snapshot in place of the actual button with the desired transparency. Show the button once you have reached an alpha value of `255`. This is similar to how [`AnimateWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx) works.

Comment: I tested it on Windows 10, so I think it's the manifest that I'm missing. Thanks for pointing that out! I never knew about that for C++ applications.